# Connecting windows 7 phone emulator to own website?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

Marcus here. I have encounter a problem which i have difficulties in solving. Apparently, i have an example of the coding of windows 7 phone connecting to dotnetzonereader. Well i tried changing the url address to www.google.com but it is unable to do so. Over here I'm not referring to the internet explorer in windows 7 emulator accessing www.google.com , however I'm talking about an application accessing the internet. This is an example of the code i got from the net. I tried changing this part >             dzoneRss.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://feeds.dzone.com/zones/dotnet"));
to             dzoneRss.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://google.com"));
but there is error still. Any kind souls out here to help me with this T_T. Thanks people. Really thankyou

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;



namespace DotNetZoneReader
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void storyList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var dzoneRss = new WebClient();
            dzoneRss.DownloadStringCompleted += dzoneRss_DownloadStringCompleted;
            dzoneRss.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://feeds.dzone.com/zones/dotnet"));
        }
        private void dzoneRss_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null) return;
            XElement xmlStories = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
            XNamespace dz = "http://www.developerzone.com/modules/dz/1.0";
            storyList.ItemsSource = from story in xmlStories.Descendants("item")
                                    select new FeedItem
                                    {
                                        Title = story.Element("title").Value,
                                        Description = story.Element("description").Value,
                                        Link = story.Element("link").Value,
                                        PublishDate = Convert.ToDateTime(story.Element(dz + "submitDate").Value).ToString("dd-MMM"),
                                        Author = story.Element(dz + "submitter").Element(dz + "username").Value,
                                        AuthorImageUrl = story.Element(dz + "submitter").Element(dz + "userimage").Value
                                    };
        }
        public class FeedItem
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }
            public string PublishDate { get; set; }
            public string Author { get; set; }
            public string AuthorImageUrl { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are encountering? And what are you trying to do? If the page you are loading has no XML namespace defined (and is not XML-formatted), then you will most definitely get an error anyway.

Comment: Hi Marcus, Does the code work for you before you change the url? What is the error you get and from which line?

Comment: Thanks Dennis and Mick for your answers. As i have mentioned, this is a sample of dotnetzonereader i have retrieved from the web. It would be great if u guys can copy the code i have mentioned above to your Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express For Windows Phone. Once i press the refresh button, it enables me to see the webpage http://feeds.dzone.com/zones/dotnet . However I'm trying to change it to allow me to access google. My question would be which part of the code i must change then i'm able to access google? Thanks @Mick @Dennis

Answer (score 0):

To access google, you can do this quite simply by placing a WebBrowser control on your page and setting the Source to point to google in the WebBrowser's loaded event. e.g.

```
    private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

The code you linked does different things which according to your requirements you don't need and aren't necessarily compatible with google's site.

You can accomplish the above in an empty Windows Phone Application project.

Comment: @ Mick N Thanks for the answer, was busy over the past few days. Sorry if i'm abit too annoying at this point cause i'm not really familiar around with visual studio for express phone. How can i set the source? Would it be possible if you can go abit more detailed? Sorry to trouble you. I have tried doing so.

Comment: @ Mick N 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace WindowsPhoneApplication2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

Comment: @ Mick N SupportedOrientations = SupportedPageOrientation.Portrait | SupportedPageOrientation.Landscape;
        }
        private void webBrowser1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com/", UriKind.Absolute));
        } 

    }
}

Comment: @ Mick N i occurred an error like this. 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070020

Comment: What you need to do with the code I posted is wire it up to the WebBrowser's loaded event. You can do this on the events tab, in the properties window while you have the WebBrowser control targeted in the design view. If you think you'll need detailed support you might be better posting on the windows phone forums as they support a more conversational style of posting in threads with ability to exchange code snippets etc.

Comment: @ Mick N I'm able to get it started. Am i also able to remove the http address on top of it? As in filter it away. Meaning, on the emulator, the person is unable to navigate away to other websites? By removing the address part. Am i able to do so?

Comment: If you do what I described in an empty project, there will be no address bar for the user to navigate away.